# How does this piece of code from the vue-cli work?

Tags: webpack

```
const testsContext = require.context('./specs', true, /\.spec$/)
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext)
```

I get that require.context is some sort of function that requires multiple files by searching a directory. I don't get what the keys function does and whats happening when you pass the context into the function again.

Comment: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Try the documentation: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/context#requirecontext